# Starting activity com.example.newproj.MainActivity on device emulator-5554

Tags: android

When I run application on android emulator I got stuck after this message:

```
(Starting activity com.example.newproj.MainActivity on device emulator-5554)
```

I have tried everything but nothing is working.

Please help

Comment: is your emulator already running when you try to run you app?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. Learn to wait. Higher version emulators take ages to start.
2. If not go to preferences, and check the emulator configurations by clicking on the current emulator.

Answer (score 1):

Right Click on Project.

1. Run As -> Run Configurations.
2. Select appropriate App name from the
   left Menu under **Android Application**.
3. Under the Android tab select **Launch Action : Launch Default Activity** (or) Manually **Launch Action -> Launch : -> select any Activity** to launch.
4. Click apply and Run the App in Emulator.